# Recovering Thunderbird Folders

Tags: windows-10, email, thunderbird

My father accidentally deleted several important folders from Thunderbird. I have restored them from his backup, but they aren't showing up in the folder list.

My procedure was to restore the `.sbd` folder from the backup media to a `Recovered Contents` folder, and then drag it to `App Data\Thunderbird\blah\Mail\Local Folders`, but obviously there's more to it than that. What have I missed?

Comment: How did you restore them?

Comment: @Jonno Good point. I've edited my question with a summary of what I did.

Comment: Why is this downvoted?  OP edited question to provide extra detail?